# Sum over 3 distinct indices

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I’m trying to calculate

$$\sum_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq n} 1$$

This is because I think that this quantity is the number of alphabetically ordered words of 3 letters taken from n symbols. This is since we can pick 3 letters $ijk$, but it’s required that $i < j < k$.

I’m not familiar with these kind of sums and the result I’m getting with $n=26$ is not the expected answer via:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=k+1}^n 1$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since every unordered triple of distinct numbers between $1$ and $n$ (inclusive) can be put into increasing order in exactly one way, this is just the number of such triples.  Thus $S(n)=\binom n3$.

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean that $\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < \dots < i_k \leq n} 1 = \binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: Yes, by the same argument.